# How are votes by users with less than 15 rep. recorded?

Tags: support, voting, new-users, post-feedback

When I try to upvote a question, it says that "votes from users with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed score." How are they recorded? Do they actually do anything?